# navigationBar setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault not working

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have a UICollectionView that displays image thumbnails. When clicked, the thumbnails call another view, `wallpaperView`, to show the image in full size.

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    // ...insert the usual row number check here

    UIViewController *wallpaperView = [QUOWallpaperViewController new];       
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:wallpaperView animated:YES];
}
```

(The UICollectionView itself is the root view controller of a UINavigationController object, as per usual)

Now, in `wallpaperView`, I want to **hide the navigation bar, and display my own custom button**. [I have already found a solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064626/hide-navigation-bar-but-not-the-back-button).

Following the top answer there, I put this code in `wallpaperViewController.m`:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{        
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

However, this does not work. The navbar still shows up as usual. Does anyone know why this is the case?

Comment: you can try this line to hide your navbar "self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = TRUE;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need to show your own button as bar button on navigation then there is no need to hide navigationbar i've gone through your code and made some modifications just use this one and do not hide navigation bar ok.

```
UIImage* image3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mail-48_24.png"]; 
CGRect frameimg = CGRectMake(0, 0, image3.size.width, image3.size.height); 
UIButton *someButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frameimg]; 
[someButton setBackgroundImage:image3 forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
[someButton addTarget:self action:@selector(sendmail) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
[someButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES]; 

UIBarButtonItem *mailbutton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:someButton]; 
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=mailbutton; 
[someButton release];

self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES; // Setting this slides the view up, underneath the nav bar (otherwise it'll appear black)
const float colorMask[6] = {222, 255, 222, 255, 222, 255};
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] init];
UIImage *maskedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors(img.CGImage, colorMask)];

[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:maskedImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
//remove shadow
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setShadowImage: [[UIImage alloc] init]];
```

Comment: I understand the concept you're trying to say, but I *do* want the bar to be invisible, because the design of the app requires it to be so.

Instead of hiding the bar, is it possible to make it transparent instead?

Comment: you can try this for making navigationbar transparent "[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];"

Comment: I was actually trying to make it completely invisible, so it's my own fault I didn't word it correctly. But your suggestion does make it transparent.

Comment: @hfz : Take a look at my edited answer and try it it will do your work perfectly as you need it will give you back button without navigationbar :)

Comment: You're a wizard! That does hide the bar. Now my remaining task is to use a custom button (with an image) instead of a default button for the `backButton` object. Any idea how I can accomplish this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37241/discussion-between-eptdeveloper-and-hfz)

Answer (score 0):

Try by hiding navigation controller

Inside the viewDidLoad method for your class QUOWallpaperViewController

write

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

Comment: This works.

Any idea how to show the custom back button? I tried [this piece of code](https://gist.github.com/lukecsmith/5488896#file-gistfile1-m) in the UICollectionViewController's `viewWillAppear:` method, but it's not displaying the button.

Comment: you can take custom back button for it

Comment: What do you mean with "take custom back button"?

Comment: take uibutton and set background image as per your desires and make sure you have set buttonstyle to custom

Answer (score 0):

You can write this code in ViewDidLoad method.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES;
```